# Saber si una carpeta ya terminó de copiar

Tags: java, ftp

Estoy ejecutando una aplicación java para descomprimir archivos por medio de un ftp. Paso las carpetas comprimidas a la carpeta entrada que es de donde se toman los ficheros para descomprimir y la aplicación se ejecuta todo el tiempo. El problema es que no determina si la carpeta ya terminó el copiado o aún esta en proceso. Necesito una clase que valide primero si el proceso de copiado ya finalizó y luego ejecute el descomprimido.

Comment: ¿Cómo realizas el copiado?¿Podrías añadir el código?

Comment: se hace por medio de una conexión ftp de un equipo que esta en otra ciudad a un servidor.

Comment: Y esa conexión, ¿cómo se hace?¿cómo lanzas el comando?¿usas alguna biblioteca?¿qué pasa si usas apache commons-net y yo pongo una respuesta para ftp4j o edtFTPj o...? A esta pregunta le falta información esencial para poder responder a tu problema en concreto.

Comment: @JefersonMartinez Cuando se esté **escribiendo** el archivo (o *proceso de copiado*), usa otra extensión. Cuando finalice, cambia a la extensión requerida. Google Chrome hace algo semejante con las descargas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay una forma 100% exacta y segura para conocer si la transferencia ya fue completada, pero te sugiero hacer un calculo relacionando la velocidad de transferencia, contra el tamano del archivo. Ademas, puedes generar un Checksum antes de iniciar la transferencia, y compararlo con el checksum del archivo transferido, despues del tiempo estimado del proceso.

[Aca te dejo este enlace a StackOverflow en Ingles, donde puedes checar una propuesta interesante para resolver este problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452456/how-to-know-if-file-is-complete-on-the-server-using-ftp)

Answer (score 1):

Calculando el tiempo de copiado o transferencia y poniendo un sleep saludos!

Calculo el tiempo de trasnferencia o copiado de un archivo, para luego determinar cuanto tiempo debo esperar para poder hacer la siguiente accion, ejemplo mover, cambiar bnombre, descomprimir en el caso de esta pregunta. – Gaston Barahona hace 34 segundos   editar

```
long TiempoEspera = valTiempo("miarchivo.txt");
System.out.println("Archivo: " + "miarchivo.txt"+ " Tiempo de transferencia: " + TiempoEspera + " Segundos");
Thread.sleep(1000 * TiempoEspera );
System.out.println("Archivo copiado: c:/miarchivo.txt");


private static long valTiempo(String filepath) throws InterruptedException {

        File fichero = new File(filepath);
        long pesoActual = fichero.length();
        //peso en kb
        long pesoKB = pesoActual / 1024; 
        // mega
        long pesoMB = pesoKB / 1024;  

        //Calculo de tiempo FACTOR_OSI_RED es la ocilacion de la red
        long tasaTransferencia=20;
        double FACTOR_OSI_RED =1.1;
        long tiempo = Math.round((pesoMB / tasaTransferencia ) * FACTOR_OSI_RED); 
        return tiempo;
    }
```

Comment: explica tu código

Comment: no, dale editar a tu respuesta y ahi añade esto que me explicas

Comment: Hola, si alguien quiere hacer algun aporte al codigo paraq ue funcione en un ftp en  unix o linux, es bienvenido. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como ha mencionado @Ricardo J. Chamorro en una respuesta anterior, no puedes hacer asunciones sobre la velocidad de transferencia de los archivos, por lo que utilizar un timeout y una vez termine dar por terminada la transferencia es incorrecto.

Lo correcto sería hacer, al menos, una de estas dos cosas :

1. Obtener el tamaño del fichero y entonces compararlo con el tamaño con el tamaño "transferido" cada X tiempo, utilizando un timer o como prefieras
2. Calcular un *checksum* del fichero y verificar también cada X tiempo el *checksum* del archivo en la carpeta de salida.

En realidad 2. es el que te va a asegurar con un 100% de acierto que el fichero se ha transferido y además lo ha hecho correctamente. En entornos con alta tasa de errores, podría ocurrir que tuvieras un fichero con el mismo tamaño pero corrupto.

Answer (score -1):

Cuando un archivo no ha aumentado su tamaña durante x tiempo pruebas a descomprimir. Si la descompresión funcionó todo OK. Si no, pruebas 2x, 4x...  tiempo después. Después de n intentos declaras el archivo fallido y te olvidas de el.

También puedes mirar el log del ftp, los procesos que tienen el archivo abierto etc.

Answer (score -1):

Lo solucione realizando una pausa en la aplicación con `Thread.sleep(x);`durante 3 minutos lo cual me garantiza que la descompresión se realiza completa